# Compression and encryption in PHP or C

Tags: php, c++, encryption

Given a 10M byte stream, I need to compress it (gzip or else) and encrypt it (Rijndael-128), then store it on the disk. At some point, the reverse operation will also be required.

This is part of a web app, mainly developed in PHP. I've already written this in PHP in a few lines. However, I was thinking whether writing this component in C and calling it from PHP would be better. The execution time isn't the most relevant aspect, but memory usage and CPU load are.

Based on that, is it worth writing the raw bytestream to disk and then running the C/C++ program on it to compress and encrypt?

Comment: Why not try it with a few lines of `mcrypt` first, and see if there is a problem? I'd expect the designers would have considered resource consumption when testing it!

Comment: I've already implemented it in PHP and it runs just fine. However, in the future many such operations will be requested simultaneously, and the server resources are somewhat limited(2GB of RAM and dual-core CPU). Permanent storage is fast though, server grade SSD.

Comment: Run load testing from `ab` on it to see how it performs. Or, take the encryption out of the web app and make it an offline process. Mcrypt is already written in C, so I suspect calling an encryption library from C won't get you any gains (and you should not write it yourself unless you are a complete expert, for security reasons).

Comment: Building this component in a lower-level language would take a fair amount of time. I thought someone already encountered a similar issue, as there are many questions about whether compiled C should be used instead of PHP for specific tasks.

Comment: ^ See my update about building it in C (basically, don't do it) `:)`

Comment: @user3359858: the php gzip and mcrypt functions _are_ implemented in C, so it should solve the problem fairly fast :)

Comment: I see. That's what I thought as well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Will [this article](http://technosophos.com/2012/02/28/php-stream-filters-compress-transform-and-transcode-fly.html) on PHP stream filters help you?

Comment: Interesting approach, but it isn't quite what I needed. I described my solution in the last comment of your answer, maybe a bit of further brainstorming and I can optimize it even more. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that *if* it is a stream, then handle it as a stream and to keep resource (RAM) use at a minimum - i.e. don't handle the stream as a huge byte array. Try and tweak buffer sizes.

Write a PHP library for streaming using C and AES-NI CPU instructions if it is not fast enough. You could use OpenSSL functions from PHP that already deploy AES-NI. Bothan could also be used, it is a library for C++ that focuses on streaming support and it also uses AES-NI if available.

Whatever you do, don't write the intermediate plaintext to disk, that's both insecure *and* it introduces an unnecessary I/O (+ OS access) bottleneck.

Comment: Note that the mcrypt source code seem to have gone unmaintained for a long while and does not seem to support AES-NI. I'll leave it to you what that means for security of PHP mcrypt functionality (if such a thing ever existed in the first place).

Comment: I did some tests with chunk encryption(multiple of IV size which is 16 bytes long) of 16KB and 32KB using CBC mode AES. It is a little bit slower than encrypting all the file at once(less than 10%), but the memory usage is predictable and very low. However, compression is harder to achieve by doing it on chunks rather than the entire file. Is there any way of doing that without building a sort of map with the compressed chunk lengths?

Comment: Now that I think of it, reading the stream in 32KB chunks and compressing it(before encryption), simultaneously building an array of the compressed chunks length, for a 10MB file would mean about 320 integers of 4 bytes each, which is roughly 1.25kb. I could write that to another file without ruining performance.